# Cannot set property 'url' of undefined

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

In the example below i create an instance of the `typeahead` class

```
    var ta = $.typeahead({
        input: '.super',
        minLength: 0,
        maxItem: 15,
        order: "asc",
        hint: true,
        href: "",
        searchOnFocus: true,
        display: ["name"],
        template: "{{name}}",
        source: {
            "SearchResults": {
                //ajax: {
                //    url: "/search/" + id,
                //    path: ""
                //}
            }
        },
        callback: {
            onClickAfter: function (node, a, item, event) {
                event.preventDefault;
                debugger;
            }
        },
        debug: true
    });
```

Later on, and by using the `id` variable which is obtained via the following method

```
    $("input").focus(function () { 
        id = $(this).attr("id");
        ta.source.ajax.url = "/search/" + id;
    });
```

i get the `Cannot set property 'url' of undefined` since the `ta.source.ajax` is actually null.
How can i fix that?

Simply put, i do not want to create duplicate code for each input of my form

Comment: What *are* the properties of `ta.source`?  Looks like it should be `ta.source.SearchResults.ajax.url`

Comment: *ta.source.ajax is actually null* - if it was null you would get `Cannot read property 'url' of null` - it's not null, it's the wrong property name (hence undefined)

Comment: Actually, if i use the commented code above and seting the id it works great. By the proposed solution i get Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined

Comment: Have you tried `ta.source["SearchResults"].ajax.url` ?

Comment: @freedomn-m when you assign some value to undefined property then it throws `TypeError: Cannot set property 'url' of undefined` and when you access it throws `TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined`.
@OrElse validate object property before assigning or accessing it. `if (ta.source.ajax instanceof Object) { if (ta.source.ajax.url) {  ta.source.ajax.url = "/search/" + id; } else { ta.source.ajax = { url: "/search/" + id } }} else { ta.source = { ajax: { url: "/search/" + id } } }`

Comment: @ArjunSingh I'm not sure your point.  If you assign to *undefined* you get `of undefined` if you assign to *null* you get `of null`.   They are two different messages.  OP has asserted their variable is `null` because they get `of undefined` message - which is an incorrect assertion - they get `of undefined` because it's not defined, not because it's null.

Comment: @ArjunSingh it's a simple enough test:  `var x = null; x.a = 123;` gives `of null` while `(function test(x) { x.a = 123 })();` gives `of undefined`.  `undefined !== null`

Answer (score 2):

Configure `SearchResults` group through [`options` property](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/documentation/) of the Typeahead instance.

`source` property of Typeahead instance is generated from `options`.

```
ta.options.source.SearchResults.ajax.url = "/search/" + id;
```

Comment: Getting closer. I now get No resource with given URL found.

Comment: Make sure "/search/<id>" path exists on your server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `ta.source.SearchResults.ajax.url` instead of `ta.source.ajax.url` as suggested by @freedomn

```
$("input").focus(function () { 
    id = $(this).attr("id");
    ta.source.SearchResults.ajax.url = "/search/" + id;
});
```

Also, @OrElse about your error, try leaving the properties empty and not commenting them out. Plus try removing double quotes from SearchResults --

```
source: {
    SearchResults: {
        ajax: {
            url: "/search/" + id,
            path: ""
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Unfortunatelly by doing so, I get an Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using some kind of library of jQuery. but if its loading and initializing your variable properly. and you are getting all other property then it's a small issue. Let's discuss a possible case and understand the problem

```
    var ta = $.typeahead({
            input: '.super',
            minLength: 0,
            maxItem: 15,
            order: "asc",
            hint: true,
            href: "",
            searchOnFocus: true,
            display: ["name"],
            template: "{{name}}",
            source: {
                "SearchResults": {
                    //ajax: {
                    //    url: "/search/" + id,
                    //    path: ""
                    //}
                }
            },
            callback: {
                onClickAfter: function (node, a, item, event) {
                    event.preventDefault;
                    debugger;
                }
            },
            debug: true
        });
```

when you assigning anything into the "ta" variable probably you are getting all property. but you are getting an error that "Cannot set property 'URL' of undefined". So it's clearly mentioned property which you re trying to use is URL. logically it should be ajax property but ajax itself not defined in your variable. So you should first define ajax.

```
var ta = $.typeahead({
            input: '.super',
            minLength: 0,
            maxItem: 15,
            order: "asc",
            hint: true,
            href: "",
            searchOnFocus: true,
            display: ["name"],
            template: "{{name}}",
            source: {
                "SearchResults": {
                    ajax: { // now ajax is defined and you will not get any error. 
                    }
                }
            },
            callback: {
                onClickAfter: function (node, a, item, event) {
                    event.preventDefault;
                    debugger;
                }
            },
            debug: true
        });
```

Always make sure the variable of JSON is defined previously you can define a property later.

for example

```
var a={}
a.b.c=10
console.log(a.b.c)// you will get same error.
```

but if you use something like below.

```
a.b={}
a.b.c=10 
console.log(a.b.c)// you will not get an error.
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

What about just wrapping the line in a if statement checking if `ta.source.ajax` exists to prevent it from throwing the property of null error

```
if(ta.source.ajax){
   ta.source.ajax.url = "/search/" + id;
}
```